# contador sequencial

Tags: javascript, html

Sou novo em JavaScript dai eu tenho um contador que fica contando mais eu precisava que ele ficasse com pelo menos 10 dígitos a esquerda enquanto ele esta contando

o script e o seguinte

```js
var count = new Number();
var count = 0;
function start() {
  if ((count + 1) >= 0) {
    count = count + 1;
    tempo.innerText = count;
    setTimeout('start();', 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="start();">
  <div id="tempo"></div>
</body>
```

gostaria que quando ele ficasse:

```
000001
```

em vez

```
1
```

Comment: pelo visto aqui nao vou resolver meu poblema. esse outro topico nao tira minha duvida se tirse eu nao tinha aberto outro mais ja que o moderador disse que esta duplicado faze oque nao vejo de como resolver meu poblema com o outro topico com perguntas ja respondida o meu e um contador nao insiro numeros dentro do codigo ou por imput

Comment: Ergon, se achas que não é duplicada explica na pergunta a diferênça e abrimos sem problemas. Nós fechamos para organizar o site, não por falta de qualidade ou interesse na pergunta.

Comment: Eragon, as respostas da pergunta relecionada resolvem seu problema, basta dar uma analisada e tentar entender as respostas, é bem simples, mas em todo caso, veja [esse fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60s94c2p/) que é ainda mais simples.